# Google Analytics - Not tracking in IE

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site URL: `<removed after answering>`
and it is mapped to show as app on facebook:

I'm able to track engagements on the apps.facebook url and direct URL on all browsers except IE. I have tried different solutions from people on the internet but none seem to work.

You can have a look at he source of the page to look at analytics settings. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You will see some popup's appear on the page, these are in place to track the engagement of the user. I have placed alert in "RegisterOnGA" function of the page where i use _gaq.push, to log event data. I assume that if this pop up is seen, _gaq.push has worked correctly. It seems that this is not the case with IE because there is no data log for it.

Comment: I have no iE here. Can you confirm if the google analytics cookies are being set? Maybe iE doesn't allow you to set cookies on IP addresses. No Cookies = No GA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. With help from: www.savio.no/blogg/a/104/how-to-track-facebook-iframes-with-google-analytics, i tried the solution for asp.net and it worked. Apparently it looks like cookies were not being set as expected.